# Ionic android path not 'platform' it is 'latform'

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

I have some trouble with adding android platform. I don't know what I do, but since 1-2 days I can't add android to my projects. I get this error:

[image: Path is not 'platform' it is 'latform']

Comment: Your path in the configuration is messed up. Never messed with cordova or anything, but that is a pretty confident assumption based on that error.

Comment: Actually,I didn't anyting,really ahaha I just install git last 2-3 days,as far as I remember. So,I don't know why the android install path is wrong